# MySQL join to pivot question

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is simple but my brain just isnt working today!

I have a table `products`, lets just assume it contains `p_id`, i have another table - a pivot table - which references between `products` and another table `attributes`, this table is `products_to_attributes` and contains `pta_aid` (attribute id) and `pta_pid` (product id)

Hopefully this (incorrect) query will show what i want to do better than i can explain it:

```
SELECT `p_id` FROM `products` 
LEFT JOIN `products_to_attributes` ON (`pta_pid` = `p_id`)
WHERE ((`pta_aid` = '1' OR `pta_aid` = '2') AND(`pta_aid` = '3'))
```

I want to be able to group together attributes where a product must have attribute 1 Or attribute 2 AND have attribute 3.

Comment: same field in same row can not have two values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your need correctly, you pretty much have to have two EXISTS clauses:

```
SELECT p_id FROM products PR
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p_id FROM products_to_attributes WHERE (pta_aid = 1 OR pta_aid=2) AND pta_pid=PR.p_id )
AND EXISTS (SELECT p_id FROM products_to_attributes WHERE pta_aid = 3 AND pta_pid=PR.p_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.`p_id` FROM `products` p
LEFT JOIN `products_to_attributes` pta ON (p.`p_id` = pta.`pta_pid`)
```

Name the tables and specify which field is from which table. However how a field can be both 1 and 3 in a row? there is a logical problem in your where clause.

Comment: I appreciate the logic problem but my code was essentially pseudo-code to explain the issue